# d3js returning "[object%20Object]" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property: nodes of undefined"

Tags: django, d3.js, tinymce, django-compressor

I am new to Javascript and Django. I have to animate a svg file with D3js, so to practice and understand how it works I decided to add [the miserables widget](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) to my local Django website. I have a simple view:

```
def miserable(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')
```

The url is:
`url(r'^moremiser/$','more_miserable')`and I copied both index.html and miserable.json into my template folder. When I go to the url that is supposed to display the widget all I get is a blank screen. what am I doing wrong? The person who set up the local website installed tinymce and compressor, could they be causing the problem?
here is the code for index.html and miserables.json. They both are in my templates folder:

```
#index.html       
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

    .node {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    .link {
      stroke: #999;
      stroke-opacity: .6;
    }

    </style>
    <body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var width = 960,
        height = 500;

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-120)
        .linkDistance(30)
        .size([width, height]);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
      force
          .nodes(graph.nodes)
          .links(graph.links)
          .start();

      var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
          .data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("line")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

      var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
          .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("r", 5)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
          .call(force.drag);

      node.append("title")
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

      force.on("tick", function() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
      });
    });

</script>

#miserables.json
{
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"Myriel","group":1},
    {"name":"Napoleon","group":1},
    {"name":"Mlle.Baptistine","group":1},
    {"name":"Mme.Magloire","group":1},
    {"name":"CountessdeLo","group":1},
    {"name":"Geborand","group":1},
    {"name":"Champtercier","group":1},
    {"name":"Cravatte","group":1},
    {"name":"Count","group":1},
    {"name":"OldMan","group":1},
    {"name":"Labarre","group":2},
    {"name":"Valjean","group":2},
    {"name":"Marguerite","group":3},
    {"name":"Mme.deR","group":2},
    {"name":"Isabeau","group":2},
    {"name":"Gervais","group":2},
    {"name":"Tholomyes","group":3},
    {"name":"Listolier","group":3},
    {"name":"Fameuil","group":3},
    {"name":"Blacheville","group":3},
    {"name":"Favourite","group":3},
    {"name":"Dahlia","group":3},
    {"name":"Zephine","group":3},
    {"name":"Fantine","group":3},
    {"name":"Mme.Thenardier","group":4},
    {"name":"Thenardier","group":4},
    {"name":"Cosette","group":5},
    {"name":"Javert","group":4},
    {"name":"Fauchelevent","group":0},
    {"name":"Bamatabois","group":2},
    {"name":"Perpetue","group":3},
    {"name":"Simplice","group":2},
    {"name":"Scaufflaire","group":2},
    {"name":"Woman1","group":2},
    {"name":"Judge","group":2},
    {"name":"Champmathieu","group":2},
    {"name":"Brevet","group":2},
    {"name":"Chenildieu","group":2},
    {"name":"Cochepaille","group":2},
    {"name":"Pontmercy","group":4},
    {"name":"Boulatruelle","group":6},
    {"name":"Eponine","group":4},
    {"name":"Anzelma","group":4},
    {"name":"Woman2","group":5},
    {"name":"MotherInnocent","group":0},
    {"name":"Gribier","group":0},
    {"name":"Jondrette","group":7},
    {"name":"Mme.Burgon","group":7},
    {"name":"Gavroche","group":8},
    {"name":"Gillenormand","group":5},
    {"name":"Magnon","group":5},
    {"name":"Mlle.Gillenormand","group":5},
    {"name":"Mme.Pontmercy","group":5},
    {"name":"Mlle.Vaubois","group":5},
    {"name":"Lt.Gillenormand","group":5},
    {"name":"Marius","group":8},
    {"name":"BaronessT","group":5},
    {"name":"Mabeuf","group":8},
    {"name":"Enjolras","group":8},
    {"name":"Combeferre","group":8},
    {"name":"Prouvaire","group":8},
    {"name":"Feuilly","group":8},
    {"name":"Courfeyrac","group":8},
    {"name":"Bahorel","group":8},
    {"name":"Bossuet","group":8},
    {"name":"Joly","group":8},
    {"name":"Grantaire","group":8},
    {"name":"MotherPlutarch","group":9},
    {"name":"Gueulemer","group":4},
    {"name":"Babet","group":4},
    {"name":"Claquesous","group":4},
    {"name":"Montparnasse","group":4},
    {"name":"Toussaint","group":5},
    {"name":"Child1","group":10},
    {"name":"Child2","group":10},
    {"name":"Brujon","group":4},
    {"name":"Mme.Hucheloup","group":8}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},
    {"source":3,"target":0,"value":10},
    {"source":3,"target":2,"value":6},
    {"source":4,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":5,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":6,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":7,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":8,"target":0,"value":2},
    {"source":9,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":11,"target":10,"value":1},
    {"source":11,"target":3,"value":3},
    {"source":11,"target":2,"value":3},
    {"source":11,"target":0,"value":5},
    {"source":12,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":13,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":14,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":15,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":17,"target":16,"value":4},
    {"source":18,"target":16,"value":4},
    {"source":18,"target":17,"value":4},
    {"source":19,"target":16,"value":4},
    {"source":19,"target":17,"value":4},
    {"source":19,"target":18,"value":4},
    {"source":20,"target":16,"value":3},
    {"source":20,"target":17,"value":3},
    {"source":20,"target":18,"value":3},
    {"source":20,"target":19,"value":4},
    {"source":21,"target":16,"value":3},
    {"source":21,"target":17,"value":3},
    {"source":21,"target":18,"value":3},
    {"source":21,"target":19,"value":3},
    {"source":21,"target":20,"value":5},
    {"source":22,"target":16,"value":3},
    {"source":22,"target":17,"value":3},
    {"source":22,"target":18,"value":3},
    {"source":22,"target":19,"value":3},
    {"source":22,"target":20,"value":4},
    {"source":22,"target":21,"value":4},
    {"source":23,"target":16,"value":3},
    {"source":23,"target":17,"value":3},
    {"source":23,"target":18,"value":3},
    {"source":23,"target":19,"value":3},
    {"source":23,"target":20,"value":4},
    {"source":23,"target":21,"value":4},
    {"source":23,"target":22,"value":4},
    {"source":23,"target":12,"value":2},
    {"source":23,"target":11,"value":9},
    {"source":24,"target":23,"value":2},
    {"source":24,"target":11,"value":7},
    {"source":25,"target":24,"value":13},
    {"source":25,"target":23,"value":1},
    {"source":25,"target":11,"value":12},
    {"source":26,"target":24,"value":4},
    {"source":26,"target":11,"value":31},
    {"source":26,"target":16,"value":1},
    {"source":26,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":27,"target":11,"value":17},
    {"source":27,"target":23,"value":5},
    {"source":27,"target":25,"value":5},
    {"source":27,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":27,"target":26,"value":1},
    {"source":28,"target":11,"value":8},
    {"source":28,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":29,"target":23,"value":1},
    {"source":29,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":29,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":30,"target":23,"value":1},
    {"source":31,"target":30,"value":2},
    {"source":31,"target":11,"value":3},
    {"source":31,"target":23,"value":2},
    {"source":31,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":32,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":33,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":33,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":34,"target":11,"value":3},
    {"source":34,"target":29,"value":2},
    {"source":35,"target":11,"value":3},
    {"source":35,"target":34,"value":3},
    {"source":35,"target":29,"value":2},
    {"source":36,"target":34,"value":2},
    {"source":36,"target":35,"value":2},
    {"source":36,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":36,"target":29,"value":1},
    {"source":37,"target":34,"value":2},
    {"source":37,"target":35,"value":2},
    {"source":37,"target":36,"value":2},
    {"source":37,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":37,"target":29,"value":1},
    {"source":38,"target":34,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":35,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":36,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":37,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":29,"value":1},
    {"source":39,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":40,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":41,"target":24,"value":2},
    {"source":41,"target":25,"value":3},
    {"source":42,"target":41,"value":2},
    {"source":42,"target":25,"value":2},
    {"source":42,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":43,"target":11,"value":3},
    {"source":43,"target":26,"value":1},
    {"source":43,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":44,"target":28,"value":3},
    {"source":44,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":45,"target":28,"value":2},
    {"source":47,"target":46,"value":1},
    {"source":48,"target":47,"value":2},
    {"source":48,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":48,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":48,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":49,"target":26,"value":3},
    {"source":49,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":50,"target":49,"value":1},
    {"source":50,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":51,"target":49,"value":9},
    {"source":51,"target":26,"value":2},
    {"source":51,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":52,"target":51,"value":1},
    {"source":52,"target":39,"value":1},
    {"source":53,"target":51,"value":1},
    {"source":54,"target":51,"value":2},
    {"source":54,"target":49,"value":1},
    {"source":54,"target":26,"value":1},
    {"source":55,"target":51,"value":6},
    {"source":55,"target":49,"value":12},
    {"source":55,"target":39,"value":1},
    {"source":55,"target":54,"value":1},
    {"source":55,"target":26,"value":21},
    {"source":55,"target":11,"value":19},
    {"source":55,"target":16,"value":1},
    {"source":55,"target":25,"value":2},
    {"source":55,"target":41,"value":5},
    {"source":55,"target":48,"value":4},
    {"source":56,"target":49,"value":1},
    {"source":56,"target":55,"value":1},
    {"source":57,"target":55,"value":1},
    {"source":57,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":57,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":58,"target":55,"value":7},
    {"source":58,"target":48,"value":7},
    {"source":58,"target":27,"value":6},
    {"source":58,"target":57,"value":1},
    {"source":58,"target":11,"value":4},
    {"source":59,"target":58,"value":15},
    {"source":59,"target":55,"value":5},
    {"source":59,"target":48,"value":6},
    {"source":59,"target":57,"value":2},
    {"source":60,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":60,"target":58,"value":4},
    {"source":60,"target":59,"value":2},
    {"source":61,"target":48,"value":2},
    {"source":61,"target":58,"value":6},
    {"source":61,"target":60,"value":2},
    {"source":61,"target":59,"value":5},
    {"source":61,"target":57,"value":1},
    {"source":61,"target":55,"value":1},
    {"source":62,"target":55,"value":9},
    {"source":62,"target":58,"value":17},
    {"source":62,"target":59,"value":13},
    {"source":62,"target":48,"value":7},
    {"source":62,"target":57,"value":2},
    {"source":62,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":62,"target":61,"value":6},
    {"source":62,"target":60,"value":3},
    {"source":63,"target":59,"value":5},
    {"source":63,"target":48,"value":5},
    {"source":63,"target":62,"value":6},
    {"source":63,"target":57,"value":2},
    {"source":63,"target":58,"value":4},
    {"source":63,"target":61,"value":3},
    {"source":63,"target":60,"value":2},
    {"source":63,"target":55,"value":1},
    {"source":64,"target":55,"value":5},
    {"source":64,"target":62,"value":12},
    {"source":64,"target":48,"value":5},
    {"source":64,"target":63,"value":4},
    {"source":64,"target":58,"value":10},
    {"source":64,"target":61,"value":6},
    {"source":64,"target":60,"value":2},
    {"source":64,"target":59,"value":9},
    {"source":64,"target":57,"value":1},
    {"source":64,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":65,"target":63,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":64,"value":7},
    {"source":65,"target":48,"value":3},
    {"source":65,"target":62,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":58,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":61,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":60,"value":2},
    {"source":65,"target":59,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":57,"value":1},
    {"source":65,"target":55,"value":2},
    {"source":66,"target":64,"value":3},
    {"source":66,"target":58,"value":3},
    {"source":66,"target":59,"value":1},
    {"source":66,"target":62,"value":2},
    {"source":66,"target":65,"value":2},
    {"source":66,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":66,"target":63,"value":1},
    {"source":66,"target":61,"value":1},
    {"source":66,"target":60,"value":1},
    {"source":67,"target":57,"value":3},
    {"source":68,"target":25,"value":5},
    {"source":68,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":68,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":68,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":68,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":68,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":69,"target":25,"value":6},
    {"source":69,"target":68,"value":6},
    {"source":69,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":69,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":69,"target":27,"value":2},
    {"source":69,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":69,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":25,"value":4},
    {"source":70,"target":69,"value":4},
    {"source":70,"target":68,"value":4},
    {"source":70,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":58,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":69,"value":2},
    {"source":71,"target":68,"value":2},
    {"source":71,"target":70,"value":2},
    {"source":71,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":72,"target":26,"value":2},
    {"source":72,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":72,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":73,"target":48,"value":2},
    {"source":74,"target":48,"value":2},
    {"source":74,"target":73,"value":3},
    {"source":75,"target":69,"value":3},
    {"source":75,"target":68,"value":3},
    {"source":75,"target":25,"value":3},
    {"source":75,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":75,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":75,"target":70,"value":1},
    {"source":75,"target":71,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":64,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":65,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":66,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":63,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":62,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":58,"value":1}
  ]
}
```

When I open the Javascript debugger in Google Chrome, I see that instead of going to the url "moremiser" the server try to go to "moremiser/[object%20Object] and then the other error message appears:""Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property: nodes of undefined". What should I modify?

Comment: is the status of the response 200?

Comment: No, I just checked in Bash and it is 404. Moreover, I opened the code viewer(F12  in Google Chrome) and in Frames/(127.0.0.1)/Scripts I see "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "nodes" of undefined".

Comment: Difficult to say. you did setup the urls.py correctly?

Comment: I have to wait eight hours before answering my own question, so I will add code as soon as I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I did. I think Javascript cannot locate "miserable.json" nor access the nodes in it. I say this because I have assigned the content of "miserables.json" to an object defined into "index.html" without success. Then, I created an array of nodes(without identifying them as being node), pasted the code for the array into the "index.html" file, and wrote a for loop printing as many "hello wolrd" as there are objects in the array; at first, the browser said that d3 was not defined, then it worked when I referenced the url of the online d3 library instead of the d3 folder on my computer.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
var dataset = [{"name":"Myriel","group":1},
    {"name":"Napoleon","group":1},
    {"name":"Mlle.Baptistine","group":1},
    {"name":"Mme.Magloire","group":1},
    {"name":"CountessdeLo","group":1},
    {"name":"Geborand","group":1},
    {"name":"Champtercier","group":1},
    {"name":"Cravatte","group":1},
    {"name":"Count","group":1},
    {"name":"OldMan","group":1},
    {"name":"Labarre","group":2},
    {"name":"Valjean","group":2},
    {"name":"Marguerite","group":3},
    {"name":"Mme.deR","group":2},
    {"name":"Isabeau","group":2},
    {"name":"Gervais","group":2},
    {"name":"Tholomyes","group":3},
    {"name":"Listolier","group":3},
    {"name":"Fameuil","group":3},
    {"name":"Blacheville","group":3},
    {"name":"Favourite","group":3},
    {"name":"Dahlia","group":3},
    {"name":"Zephine","group":3},
    {"name":"Fantine","group":3},
    {"name":"Mme.Thenardier","group":4},
    {"name":"Thenardier","group":4},
    {"name":"Cosette","group":5},
    {"name":"Javert","group":4},
    {"name":"Fauchelevent","group":0},
    {"name":"Bamatabois","group":2},
    {"name":"Perpetue","group":3},
    {"name":"Simplice","group":2},
    {"name":"Scaufflaire","group":2},
    {"name":"Woman1","group":2},
    {"name":"Judge","group":2},
    {"name":"Champmathieu","group":2},
    {"name":"Brevet","group":2},
    {"name":"Chenildieu","group":2},
    {"name":"Cochepaille","group":2},
    {"name":"Pontmercy","group":4},
    {"name":"Boulatruelle","group":6},
    {"name":"Eponine","group":4},
    {"name":"Anzelma","group":4},
    {"name":"Woman2","group":5},
    {"name":"MotherInnocent","group":0},
    {"name":"Gribier","group":0},
    {"name":"Jondrette","group":7},
    {"name":"Mme.Burgon","group":7},
    {"name":"Gavroche","group":8},
    {"name":"Gillenormand","group":5},
    {"name":"Magnon","group":5},
    {"name":"Mlle.Gillenormand","group":5},
    {"name":"Mme.Pontmercy","group":5},
    {"name":"Mlle.Vaubois","group":5},
    {"name":"Lt.Gillenormand","group":5},
    {"name":"Marius","group":8},
    {"name":"BaronessT","group":5},
    {"name":"Mabeuf","group":8},
    {"name":"Enjolras","group":8},
    {"name":"Combeferre","group":8},
    {"name":"Prouvaire","group":8},
    {"name":"Feuilly","group":8},
    {"name":"Courfeyrac","group":8},
    {"name":"Bahorel","group":8},
    {"name":"Bossuet","group":8},
    {"name":"Joly","group":8},
    {"name":"Grantaire","group":8},
    {"name":"MotherPlutarch","group":9},
    {"name":"Gueulemer","group":4},
    {"name":"Babet","group":4},
    {"name":"Claquesous","group":4},
    {"name":"Montparnasse","group":4},
    {"name":"Toussaint","group":5},
    {"name":"Child1","group":10},
    {"name":"Child2","group":10},
    {"name":"Brujon","group":4},
    {"name":"Mme.Hucheloup","group":8}];

d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
    .text("New paragraph!")
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```